# Hive Date conversion from MMM DD YYYY datTo date

Tags: hive

Can you help to get an answer in hive?
Source: Sat Nov 25 2017

Output should be: 2017-11-25 00:00:00

I am using the below logic but it is not working 
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr('Sat Nov 25 2017',5,15),'MMM DD YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD');

Regards,
mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You were not too far. Case of the formatting pattern matters!

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr('Sat Nov 25 2017',5,15), 'MMM dd yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Output

```
2017-11-25 00:00:00
```